# How to force map to panTo with animation?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As the API describes about panTo()

> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is
>   less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be
>   smoothly animated.

but if we need a mechanism to animate even if the change is greater than the width/height of the map, how can we do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?